# How to exit recursion

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

With my code below the problem is the found is false.
It finds the password and gets to the `return true;` but it keeps on running.
How can back out of the recursion and stop at `return true;`?

```
    string password = "password";
    char[] chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's' , 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    bool found = MatchPassword(chars, 8, string.Empty, password);
    Debug.WriteLine(found);
}

static int counter = 0;
public static bool MatchPassword(char[] chars, int maxLen, string baseGuess, string actualPassword)
{
    counter++;
    int curLen = baseGuess.Length;
    if (curLen == maxLen)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        string nextGuess = baseGuess + chars[i];
        if (counter % 1000000 == 0 || curLen == 0 || nextGuess.StartsWith("passwo")) //
            Debug.WriteLine(nextGuess);
        if (nextGuess == actualPassword)
            return true;
        else
            MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do something with the result of `MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);` i.e. `boolean shouldWeBailOut = MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);` then `if shouldWeBailOut return true`

Comment: You need to `return` the value from the recursive call: `else return MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
 else if (Match...) return true;
```

Or even:

```
    if (nextGuess == actualPassword || Match...)
        return true;
```

Because you want to continue iterations when current fails and stop if something found.

Answer (score 5):

add a return before

```
MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);
```

that line should probably be:

```
return MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);
```

That way you basically "bubble up" the result back up the call stack

Comment: It gets to 'a' and returns false

Comment: @Paparazzi you should probably step through your code, you have other issues going on besides returning.

Comment: You can't just return because a loop. It should be returned if and only if match was found.

Comment: @vp_auth, yes you can, return breaks the loop and exits the function.

Comment: Well I uses the answer from vp_arth and it seems to be working

Comment: You can, yes. But what a loop means then? You always break first iteration with your return.

Comment: I guess I assumed this was a traditional recursive function, not a looping/recursive hybrid.  In a true recursive function, the function calls ARE the loop.  This looks more like a homework assignment that was shoe horned into a recursive call because it was required

Comment: @NeilN It is more than common in recursion (except maybe in haskell) to only bubble up the result if the match is found, otherwise keep iterating.

Answer (score 2):

You never do anything with the result of your recursive call:

```
    if (nextGuess == actualPassword)
        return true;
    else
        MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword); //Here
```

Then your code just keeps falling through the your final `return false`

You should return the result of the recursive call like so

```
    if (nextGuess == actualPassword)
        return true;
    else
        return MatchPassword(chars, maxLen, nextGuess, actualPassword);
```

Comment: It get to 'a' and returns false